# Bug with Chrome miss calculating iframe content height

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For some strange reason, Chrome cannot correctly calculate iframe content height. Firefox looks like to do it correctly.

Take a look at the code below which is the minimum necessary to trigger the bug:

Live demo on: https://www.quemfazsite.com.br/temp/teste.php (I didnt put the code in the js playground because in this particular case it does not work there because of iframe inside iframe)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Height of the content of iframe calculated every 100ms: <span id="height_of_iframe" style="font-weight:bold;"></span></div>

<br>

<div onclick="$('#xxx').contents().find('body').append('<div>APPENDED</div>');" style="cursor:pointer;">ADD ELEMENT</div>
<div onclick="$('#xxx').contents().find('div:last').remove();" style="cursor:pointer;">REMOVE ELEMENT</div>

<br>

<iframe id="xxx" src="about:blank" style="width:100%;"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        
    $("#xxx").contents().find("body").css("background","#FFF000").html('<div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div>');

    window.setInterval(

        function() {

            var temp3376 = $("#xxx").contents().get(0);

            $("#height_of_iframe").text(temp3376.body.scrollHeight + " | " + temp3376.body.offsetHeight + " | " + temp3376.documentElement.clientHeight + " | " + temp3376.documentElement.scrollHeight + " | " + temp3376.documentElement.offsetHeight);

            $("#xxx").css({height:Math.max(temp3376.body.scrollHeight, temp3376.body.offsetHeight,temp3376.documentElement.clientHeight, temp3376.documentElement.scrollHeight,temp3376.documentElement.offsetHeight) + "px"});

        },
        100
        
    );
    
});
</script>
```

It shows every 100ms the calculated height of the content of iframe using several methods. After runing the demo above, try clicking the ADD ELEMENT button - you will see that Chrome correctly calculates the height of the content of the iframe. Now try clicking the REMOVE ELEMENT button, you will see the calculated height never decreases (this does not happen on Firefox, which correctly calculates the new height).

Do you have any idea how can I correctly calculate the new height on Chrome?